# Xcode keeps guessing and interpreting with wrong encoding

Tags: xcode, encoding, utf-8, utf, mac-roman

I am using Xcode 4.0.2, the latest release of Xcode. All my projects or standelone source codes are in UTF-8 encoding. But when I open some source file (C/C++/Objective C), all text is interpreted in Mac OS Roman encoding and I don't know why. I've tried remove and delete all Xcode files by uninstalling Xcode. So reinstalling doesn't help. All source codes are opened in Mac OS Roman encoding. In Xcode settings I have default encoding UTF-8 (but that is for new files I think). Also I've tried reinstall libiconv that Xcode may use for detecting encodings.

I don't know about anything that may caused this. I didn't make any changes to my system, programs or data and I am sure, this I didn't have this problem one week ago.

Anyone?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

If you open up the right side view (top right view buttons) there are some settings.

Try setting the encoding there under 'text settings' for that file.

You may need to copy in your text again if the reinterpretation doesn't work.